# Entity Framework fails to get child elements

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite, entity-framework-6

I have SQLite db and these EF models and context.

Models and Context

```
public class CardHolder
{
    public int CardHolderId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string TenantName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<AccessCard> AccessCards { get; set; }
}

public class AccessCard
{
    public int AccessCardId { get; protected set; }
    public CardHolder CardHolder { get; set; }
    public DateTime ActivationDate { get; protected set; }
    public bool ActivationProcessed { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DeactivationDate { get; protected set; }
    public string DeactivationReason { get; set; }
    public bool DeactivationProcessed { get; set; }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<CardHolder> CardHolders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AccessCard> AccessCards { get; set; }
}
```

And the Main program

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var db = new MyContext())
        {
            var cardHolders = db.CardHolders.Include("AccessCard").ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

**Question1: Why do I get this exception**

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'A specified Include path is not
>   valid. The EntityType 'SQLiteDemo.Models.CardHolder' does not declare
>   a navigation property with the name 'AccessCard'.'

[image]

If I replace it with

```
var cardHolders = db.CardHolders.Include("AccessCards").ToList();
```

I get another error:

> SQL logic error no such column: Extent2.CardHolder_CardHolderId

**What is wrong with Entity Framework?**

**Question2: Why cant I use arrow function in Include statement, it doesnt compile at all?**

[image]

```
var cardHolders = db.CardHolders.Include(x => x.AccessCards).ToList();
```

**Question3: Why do I need to use Include at all if my ICollection association property AccessCards is NOT virtual - that means eager loading must work by itself!**

Why the hell it is so problematic and buggy? Nothing works as it should :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - You have a typo as you have already determined :)

1B - "SQL logic error no such column: Extent2.CardHolder_CardHolderId"

EF isn't finding your FK. You could add it to your AccessCard model:

```
public int CardHolderId { get; set; }
```

2 - You need to pull in the LINQ extensions. Make sure you have both of these using statements at the top:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
```

3 - You, like many others, are misunderstanding [lazy loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx). Eager loading still requires an `Include()` to fetch related data. Lazy loading only fetches the relations when you access them.

Comment: I had "using System.Ling" but didnt have "using System.Data.Entity", that's why Link didnt work with EF entities. Added CardHolderId property to AccessCard model, it solved the problem :) Thanks.